# printf UTF8 characters with printf from Hexadecimal ints

Tags: c, utf-8, printf

Kind of trivial thing but ...
I want to print japanese characters using plain C from Hexadecimals

From [this table](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/japanesecharthiragana.html), I know that, the first char in the table, あ's Entity is &# 12353 and its Hex Entity is x3041, etc.

But how do I use this two numbers in order to get printed all characters in the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your terminal is set to UTF-8 and locale is set correctly, you may write:

```
char s[]="あ";
```

you can also try

```
 char s[]={0xe3,0x81,0x82,0x0}
```

(the last is the Unicode UTF-8 encoding for "あ"), and then just `printf("%s",s);`

Comment: I believe the UTF-8 for `0x3041` is actually `0xe3 0x81 0x81`.

Comment: Hm..."あ" is U+3042 HIRAGANA LETTER A UTF-8: e3 81 82  UTF-16BE: 3042  Decimal: &#12354, I think maybe he got it wrong, or the symbol is wrong. I'm using the `unicode` app in linux cutting and pasting the symbol from the browser..., but in any case, if it's U+3041 HIRAGANA LETTER SMALL A, then yes, you're right and UTF-8: e3 81 81

Answer (score 3):

If `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined, `wchar_t` is in Unicode, and you can do something like:

```
printf("%lc", (wchar_t)0x3041);
```